# How to convert string values from a list inside a dictionary, into float datatypes?

Tags: python, string, list, dictionary, int

I have a dictionary as follows

```
data = {'CNN': ['5.89', '2.34'], 'BBC': ['6.78', '4.45']}
```

How do I convert the Strings in value lists into float?

So it becomes

```
data = {'CNN': [5.89, 2.34], 'BBC': [6.78, 4.45]}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a dict-comprehension and `map`:

```
data = {k : list(map(float, v)) for k, v in data.items()}
```

Output:

```
{'CNN': [5.89, 2.34], 'BBC': [6.78, 4.45]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here a solution:

```
data = {'CNN': ['5.89', '2.34'], 'BBC': ['6.78', '4.45']}
data_float = {}
for k,v in data.items():
    data_float[k] = [float(elem) for elem in v]

data_float
```

Output:

```
{'BBC': [6.78, 4.45], 'CNN': [5.89, 2.34]}
```

Answer (score 0):

The two answers already posted create new dictionaries which, if they really are that small, might be of no consequence.

If, however, the dictionary was very large, a better option may be to simply convert the strings to float in place within the existing dictionary.

```
data = {'CNN': ['5.89', '2.34'], 'BBC': ['6.78', '4.45']}

for k in data.keys():
    for i in range(len(data[k])):
        data[k][i] = float(data[k][i])
```

Output

```
{'CNN': [5.89, 2.34], 'BBC': [6.78, 4.45]}
```